# How to find a distance between categorical data

Tags: python, pandas

I plan to calculate distance between categorical data (Distance From First Dataset to Second Dataset)

Here's my dataset

First Dataset

```
Id    City         Phone
A1    Jakarta      Samsung
A2    Surabaya     Apple
A3    Singapore    Sony
```

Second Dataset (as Input)

```
Id    City         Phone
1     Jakarta      Samsung
2     Singapore    Xiaomi
3     Surabaya     Sony
```

Reference table for `City`

```
             Jakarta  Surabaya    Singapore
Jakarta            0         1           2
Surabaya           1         0           1
Singapore          2         1           0
```

Reference table for `Phone`

```
               Apple   Samsung        Sony      Xiaomi
Apple              0         1           2           3
Samsung            1         0           1           2
Sony               2         1           0           1
Xiaomi             3         2           1           0
```

Second Dataset (as Output)
Calculation

```
Id    City         Phone          A1        A2        A3
1     Jakarta      Samsung       0+0       1+1       2+1
2     Singapore    Xiaomi        1+2       2+3       0+1
3     Surabaya     Sony          1+1       0+2       2+0
```

As I try to calculate distance between every single rows on first dataset and second dataset Final Output

```
Id    City         Phone          A1        A2        A3
1     Jakarta      Samsung         0         2         3
2     Singapore    Xiaomi          3         5         1
3     Surabaya     Sony            2         2         2
```

Notes:
`A1, A2, A3` is rows in first dataset

What I did is using a lot of joins, but the amount of code is too much

Comment: Can you say what you are aiming to achieve, what you've tried to solve this problem and why those solutions were unsatisfactory for you?

Comment: I have no idea which numbers are being used in your calculations. I think you will need to provide more detail. If you provide code and an explanation, then more likely to get an answer.

Comment: I think you might have an error. Or at least some contradictory data. Both Apple and Sony have assigned the same City so they should have distance 0 in your (what I assume is) nodal distances matrix. If I'm understanding correctly, I would collapse all results to a single distance matrix and use a dictionary. What is the logic you are following? Can you share what you already did?

Comment: @MichelG it is not one-on-one assign

Comment: A2    Surabaya should not have value more than 1 check you A2 output in final df

Comment: What is the relation between first and second dataset? How do you decide columns "A1, A2, A3" in second output dataset?

Comment: @AzharKhan, I try to calculate distance between every single rows on first dataset and second dataset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use cross join for all combinations of rows between both DataFrames, then add new columns by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html), sum both columns and last reshape by [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df = df2.merge(df1, how='cross', suffixes=('','_'))
df = df.join(City.stack().rename('C'), on=['City','City_'])
df = df.join(Phone.stack().rename('P'), on=['Phone','Phone_'])

df['Both'] = df['C'].add(df['P'])
print (df)
   Id       City    Phone Id_      City_   Phone_  C  P  Both
0   1    Jakarta  Samsung  A1    Jakarta  Samsung  0  0     0
1   1    Jakarta  Samsung  A2   Surabaya    Apple  1  1     2
2   1    Jakarta  Samsung  A3  Singapore     Sony  2  1     3
3   2  Singapore   Xiaomi  A1    Jakarta  Samsung  2  2     4
4   2  Singapore   Xiaomi  A2   Surabaya    Apple  1  3     4
5   2  Singapore   Xiaomi  A3  Singapore     Sony  0  1     1
6   3   Surabaya     Sony  A1    Jakarta  Samsung  1  1     2
7   3   Surabaya     Sony  A2   Surabaya    Apple  0  2     2
8   3   Surabaya     Sony  A3  Singapore     Sony  1  0     1


df = df.pivot(['Id','City','Phone'],'Id_','Both').rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()
print (df)
   Id       City    Phone  A1  A2  A3
0   1    Jakarta  Samsung   0   2   3
1   2  Singapore   Xiaomi   4   4   1
2   3   Surabaya     Sony   2   2   1
```

Comment: I've been looking for a solution to remove that "Id_" column label after pivoting. Found the solution as `.rename_axis(None, axis=1)` in your answer. ++ for that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it. You can cross join the first and second datasets and use .loc lookups by city and phone.

PS - the count you have given in the expected output is incorrect as mentioned in the comments.

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[ ["A1","Jakarta","Samsung"], ["A2","Surabaya","Apple"], ["A3","Singapore","Sony"] ], columns=["Id","City","Phone"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[ [1,"Jakarta","Samsung"], [2,"Singapore","Xiaomi"], [3,"Surabaya","Sony"] ], columns=["Id","City","Phone"])
city_df = pd.DataFrame(data=[ ["Jakarta",0,1,2], ["Surabaya",1,0,1], ["Singapore",2,1,0] ], columns=["city","Jakarta","Surabaya","Singapore"]).set_index("city")
phone_df = pd.DataFrame(data=[ ["Apple",0,1,2,3], ["Samsung",1,0,1,2], ["Sony",2,1,0,1], ["Xiaomi",3,2,1,0] ], columns=["phone","Apple","Samsung","Sony","Xiaomi"]).set_index("phone")

df1["dummy_key"] = 0
df2["dummy_key"] = 0
final_df = df2.merge(df1, on="dummy_key", how="outer")

final_df["dist"] = final_df.apply(lambda row: city_df.loc[row["City_x"], row["City_y"]] + phone_df.loc[row["Phone_x"], row["Phone_y"]], axis=1)
final_df = final_df.drop(["City_y", "Phone_y", "dummy_key"], axis=1)
final_df = final_df.rename(columns={"Id_x": "Id", "City_x": "City", "Phone_x": "Phone"})
final_df = final_df.pivot(index=["Id", "City", "Phone"], columns="Id_y", values="dist").rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
Id       City    Phone  A1  A2  A3
 1    Jakarta  Samsung   0   2   3
 2  Singapore   Xiaomi   4   4   1
 3   Surabaya     Sony   2   2   1
```

Comment: I choose this as best answer becouse this one suit my needs